# Looking for the latest Infinispan - MongoDB compatibility details

Tags: mongodb, infinispan

Where can I find the latest compatibility details for Infinispan and MongoDB.  A compatibility matrix would be ideal.

I've checked on the Infinispan website doc page (https://infinispan.org/docs/cachestores/mongodb) and nothing is available.

I'm trying find out which version of Infinispan is compatible with MongoDB 4.4

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB cache store is not being maintained (AFAIK, nobody is using it). You can try to compile it yourself to see if it works with MongoDB 4.4. The source code is here: [MongoDB cache store](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-cachestore-mongodb).

I'm not sure if it compiles against the latest Infinispan release.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  According to the docs on in this repo, the last driver compatibility version was 3.0.4. (https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-cachestore-mongodb/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/index.adoc)

This may be the way to go.   

We'll keep you posted on how we proceed.

Comment: MongoDB 3.3.0 see https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-cachestore-mongodb/blob/master/pom.xml#L86. Feel free to join our chat if you have any question: https://infinispan.zulipchat.com/